# how to sort an array by integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am trying to sort my score board but the score board is sorted by name but i want sort it by score i.e (high to low) score plese help to solve this.i stored the playername  and score details in one label.
please help me 
thanks in advance

asd  45
asd  66
rrr  55
tes  42

i want to show like

asd 66
rrr 55
asd 45
tes 42

```
-(void)btnSaveScore
{
    if(!dictWinData)
        dictWinData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ScoreName"] mutableCopy];
    if([array count] == 0)
    {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strNameOFPlayer];
    NSString *strScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iTap]];
    int intScore = iTap;
    NSLog(@"iTap data is:--> %d",intScore);

    if([strNameOFPlayer length]==7)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                   %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 6)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                     %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 5)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                       %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 4)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                         %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 3)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                           %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 2)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                             %@",strName,strScore]];
    else if ([strNameOFPlayer length] == 1)
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@                              %@",strName,strScore]];


    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sorters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sorter, nil];
    [sorter release];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters];
    [sorters release];


    NSUserDefaults *dfltsData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [dfltsData setObject:sortedArray forKey:@"ScoreName"];
    //        [dfltsData setObject:array forKey:@"ScoreCard"];
    [dfltsData synchronize];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                    message:@"Score is saved."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are adding the string (containing name and score) to the array. Instead, create a model class with the name (NSString*) and score (NSNumber*) members and add them to the array.

For sorting,

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourUnsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([[obj1 score] integerValue] > [[obj2 score] integerValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([[obj1 score] integerValue] < [[obj2 score] integerValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: +1 (have nearly the same answer in my clipboard right now). But why do you do the `(NSComparisonResult)` casts?

Comment: Thanks &Adhira...can you please tell me in the exact way how it should be? Because I am not getting what you are telling.

Comment: @Kai...can you please put the link over here...because i am not able to find out the answer you have suggested to me...thanks.